# TYPO3 showAction Function - show simple site

Tags: php, typo3

I am working on an extension for typo3.
On the List.html file I have input a table, which creates an URL

```
<f:for each="{datas}" as="data">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <f:link.action action="show" arguments="{uid: data.uid}">{data.bezeichnung}</f:link.action>
                </td>
                <td>{data.uid}</td>
            </tr>
        </f:for>
```

So far it's working fine.
Now I want to add a showAction Controller, which should show a simple Show.html file. The Show.html file looks like this:

```
<div class="action_fields">
    <input type="submit" value="Zurück">
</div>
```

Later I will put some data in it but first of all just want the site to appear.

My Controller  has this function in it:

```
public function showAction() {
    return $this->htmlResponse();
}
```

Everytime I click on a link I just got: Oops, an error occurred! Code: 202304131415135166b57f

Can someone help me why?

Comment: Did you try to search for the error code in the log file which is located in `var/log` or `typo3temp/var/log`? Can you update your question the the details from the log message?

Comment: Do you have two `XyzController` classes? If yes: You should use the same controller class for your `listAction` and `showAction` methods. Or if you want to use separate controller classes, you have to add a `controller` attribute to the `<f:link.action>` tag in your `List.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem could be solved with allowing the list action first in the ext_localconf.php file.

Posting this anwser for all other people who need it.